# How long does it take to unlock another frame by playing one of the base frames?

Tags: firefall

I'd like to get an advanced frame in Firefall. I've been told that I can use "Pilot Tokens" to unlock other frames without having to pay money.

How soon would I be able to unlock an advanced frame? Do I have to level a base frame all the way to level 40? More than once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get a new battleframe without paying any real money.

- Level any frame to 40 to receive 10 pilot tokens
- Get lucky at the slots
- Purchase one from the marketplace

Most new players I've talked to said they were able to save up enough credits (marketplace) in a very short time, much quicker than leveling all the way to 40.

Comment: Can you include how many tokens are needed to buy a new frame?

Comment: you need 10 tokens to unlock a new frame. last I checked the "get level 40 for 10 tokens" was a quick solution when they reworked everything, I'm not sure how relevant this answer still is as I no longer play FireFall.

Answer (score 1):

**You will have to level a frame all the way to *Level 40*.**

At that point, you will receive *10 Pilot Tokens*, which you can use to purchase and unlock an advanced frame.